# Clojure: treat multiple arguments to < and +

Tags: clojure

Clojure allows for binary functions (every binary function?), in particular, `+`, to be applied to multiple args:

```
(+ 1 2 3) ; 6
```

I understand how it's treated (reduce-like on the list of arguments):

```
(+ (+ 1 2) 3) => (+ 3 3) => 6
```

Let's consider relations, say, <, = etc.:

```
(< 1 2 3) ; true
```

But now I don't understand how Clojure treats it. It can not be like in the sample above, because (< 1 2) is boolean value and comparison against integer is pointless:

```
(< 1 2 3) => (< (< 1 2) 3) => (< true 3) ; bad!
```

It's incorrect. In case of relations, there should be hidden `and` inside:

```
(< 1 2 3 4) => (and (< 1 2) (< 2 3) (< 3 4))
```

This is the questions. How are they treated? I mean, for me it's like there is no uniform treatment for functions (arg list essentially reduced with this function) and comparisons. Does Clojure make distinction between these cases?

Comment: This is where (source <) comes in handy!

Comment: @Chiron This is where I'd like to say +10. I use edit-run file loop instead of repl, I haven't get used to this type of dev yet:)

Comment: Just to pick a nit, + and < are not binary functions in clojure, + is a function of 0 or more arguments, < is a function of 1 or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/<)

> Returns non-nil if nums are in monotonically increasing order,
>   otherwise false.

Likewise for `>` nums must be in monotonically decreasing order.

If you read the source (linked from the docs), you see it's equivalent to your "hidden `and`"

```
([x y & more]
   (if (< x y)
     (if (next more)
       (recur y (first more) (next more))
       (< y (first more)))
     false)))
```

Comment: Oh, I see. This is not the feature of the compiler, but a feature of the function. So I was wrong thinking compiler can do it automatically. Instead, programmer should provide an overload and treat list as he thinks right.

Comment: `+` is an ordinary function, too, not a macro or special form. The code for its multi-arg form is [`([x y & more] (reduce1 + (+ x y) more))`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c6756a8bab137128c8119add29a25b0a88509900/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L936).

Comment: I thought two args -> multiple args is compiler magic, but instead, it's just overload.

Answer (score 2):

Just read the docs:

"Returns non-nil if nums are in monotonically increasing order,
otherwise false."